# Using Lipschitz to Prove Solutions are Continuable on R

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, dynamical-systems

$x ^ { \prime } = \cos \left( x ^ { 2 } \right)$

Given the above equation, I need to show that it determines a dynamical system.

So, since this cannot be directly solved, I tried using Lipschitz to prove that each solution is contuinable on $R$.

Thus, I defined a function $f(x)$ as follows.

$f ( x ) = \cos \left( x ^ { 2 } \right)$

$f ^ { \prime } ( x ) = - 2 x \cdot \sin \left( x ^ { 2 } \right)$

I have taken two arbitrary points $x_1, x_2$ and applied mean value theorem on $(x_2,x_1)$.

$\frac { f \left( x _ { 2 } \right) - f \left( x _ { 1 } \right) } { x _ { 2 } - x _ { 1 } } = f ^ { \prime } ( c )$

$= > \quad \left| f \left( x _ { 2 } \right) - f \left( x _ { 1 } \right) \right| = \left| x _ { 2 } - x _ { 1 } \right| f ^ { \prime } ( x )$

$= > \left| f \left( x _ { 2 } \right) - f \left( x _ { 1 } \right) \right| = | - 2 c | \cdot \left| \sin \left( c ^ { 2 } \right) \right|$

However, the right hand side has no supremum on $R$. I got stuck at that point.

Comment: I don't know what it means to define a dynamical system. But does this improved inequality help:-

$$ |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \le \min(2, 2|x_1-x_2| )?$$

Comment: Thanks man, It would be great help! I failed to see that.

Comment: Great, glad to help!